# Replacing some innerTexts in a HTML string with span class and publishing back to DOM

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

I have a HTML string ( not DOM element ) like :

```
  <p>This is a sample dataa<p>
  <img src="Randomz" alt="Randomz Image">Randomz is the name of the image</img>
```

I need to append a `<span class="spellerror"></span>` to the words that have problem and that too only the Textual contents need to be checked and appended .

```
  <p>This is a sample dataa<p>
  <img src="Randomz" alt="Randomz Image"><span class="spellerror"> Randomz </span> is the name of the image</img>
```

My problem is that this is a mix of HTML and regex . Is it possible:

1. To make this some kind of a DOM element and then work on it ?
2. Or is there a regex way to achieve this.

I dont want to touch the attributes and if I modify Text contents , how do I publish it back ...because I need some HTML inserted there .

Comment: I need to rephasize that I only have a HTML string and not a DOM element . So any DOM methods would not directly make sense unless I convert them to that structure .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont love this solution, but it works:

```
'<img src="Randomz" alt="Randomz Image">Randomz is the name of the image</img>'
    .match(/<[^>]+>|[^<]+|<\/[^>]+>/g)
    .map(function (text, index) {
        if (index === 1) {
            return text.replace(/(Randomz)/, '<span class="spellerror">$1</span>');
        } else {
            return text;
        }
    })
    .join('');
```

The regex splits into opening tag, innerText, closing tag.
Then iterates on all members, if its the innerText, it replaces with desired text
Then joins.

Im stil trying to think of something less round-about but thats all i got

Comment: OK I just realised the flaw because its also alt tags, i will update in 2 minues

Comment: Wont that replace every existence of the word ? Even an attribute for example . I dont need that . Only Textual contents .

Comment: Thanks for inspiring me to think on those lines , I will try to shorten this one a bit .

Answer (score 1):

Use some form of templating:

```
String.prototype.template = String.prototype.template ||
        function (){
            var  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
                ,str = this
            ;
            function replacer(a){
                var aa = Number(a.substr(1))-1;
                return args[aa];
            }
            return  str.replace(/(\$\d+)/gm,replacer);
 };
 var thestring = [ '<p>This is a sample dataa</p><img src="Randomz"'
                  ,' alt="Randomz Image">$1Randomz$2 '
                  ,'is the name of the image</img>'].join('')
    ,nwString = theString.template('<span class="spellerror">','</span>');
```